# Restore previous version of Google Doc

Tags: google-drive-api

This morning, I was writing in a Google doc of some notes that are very important to our business. Something was wrong with my keyboard, it was emitting wrong characters, and it must have selected and erased everything, I guess. When I came back this afternoon, the doc was there, but empty.
I open the doc now, and ^Z or Edit -> Undo doesn't seem to do anything. I can open things like Version History, or (clicking on the File in Google Drive), Details and Activity. But none of them show anything but the current empty version. They show when previous activity happened, but not how to get those versions.
What can be done to get this file back? Thanks much.

Comment: If there's nothing in the doc's version history, then I'm afraid not much.

Comment: Well, when someone types in a Google doc, does that create a "version"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it back! What I had been doing wrong: Using Opera instead of Chrome. Opera showed the versions, but no arrow on the left to click on to get them back.
I saw instructions on Google Forums to clear cache, so I did that too; don't know if it helped.